# How do I remove all F-Curve modifiers in the Blender graph editor?

Tags: modifiers, graph-editor, fcurves

I need to clear all the F-Curve modifiers in Blender. I currently have the "Stepped interpolation" on every channel in the graph editor. I need a way to remove them all without going through each one manually.
Here is my current display:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I share the following python script that I modified to remove all "Stepped interpolation" F-Curve modifiers on all objects.  (I had been testing for 'CYCLES' modifiers to remove.)  And you can edit to look at only bpy.context.selected_objects, instead of all objects.

```
import bpy
        
for o in bpy.data.objects:

    if o.animation_data is not None and o.animation_data.action is not None:
        action = o.animation_data.action
        # Iterate over all F-Curves
        for fcu in action.fcurves:

            # Iterate over all F-Curve modifiers
            for mod in fcu.modifiers:

                # Only act upon "Stepped interpolation" modifiers
                if mod.type == 'STEPPED':
                    print( fcu, mod, mod.type )
                    fcu.modifiers.remove( mod )
```

If you're not used to python scripting:

1. create or open a (new) Scripting Workspace view
2. In the text editor panel, click on +New
3. copy and paste the above script
4. Menu :: Text :: Run Script